# iOS: Other music app via dock connector

Tags: ios, podcasts, lightning, music.app, spotify

I have an iPhone connected to external audio equipment via the dock connector.

The phone is equipped with three apps for playing audio: Apple Music, Apple Podcasts and Spotify. I would like to use any of these, with playing and controlling them via the dock connector, including browsing the respective music library.

Just starting the app and having it running in the foreground does the trick only half-way. This plays audio from the app, I can do pause/play and it shows track information (artist/album/track) for the currently playing track. However, for Podcasts and Spotify it does not show the library contents while playing audio.

It seems that the music app is not the only app to allow browsing the library. I had a case where I was playing audio from Spotify while the audio equipment showed the content of the Podcasts app library.

Is there a way to choose which app gets fully controlled by the dock connector?

In case this matters: the phone is an iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1, the audio equipment is an Audi A6 4F with AMI and MMI 2G.